# File Picker Appsmith not parsing object correctly when quotation marks are used

Tags: csv, filepicker, appsmith

The csv provided uses quotation marks beacuse there are commas inside the value
[image]

the filepicker uses a array of object to manage data, the issue is that the row with quotation marks is taken as a single value field of the object and the other fields are empty.
It is not parsed correctly.
Am I missing something about this ?

I expected that the array of object is parsed correctly